# How to modify dayClick on full calendar to only highlight a specific day/time

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Based on the example from full calendar documentation:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

        if (allDay) {
            alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + date);
        }else{
            alert('Clicked on the slot: ' + date);
        }

        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

        alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

        // change the day's background color just for fun
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

    }
});
```

How can I highlight only the time and day where I'm clicking on?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean highlight only the time you are clicking on? If you are talking about a certain timeslot eg if you click 11:30 and you want to highlight from  11:00 to 12:00 it is not possible. You can either make a "selection" by having `selectable : true` or you can create an event on the clicked timeslot

Answer (score 0):

That's very tricky. Basically fullcalendar is created by overlaying two table html objects: one display columns, another rows. Derivative of this is that you can only select (i mean "jquery-like" select) either whole row or day.

If you want to just highlight time i recommand you to use
[fullcalendar's select function.](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_method/)

If selection is for some reason uncomfortable for you (ie. if u use selection in other point of calendar workflow) the only other known method (known by me and my research seems to confirm this as only method) is to draw some kind of overlying div on absolute position which will be dynamically calculated (do the math - [offset() jquery function](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) can be in help here).

Godspeed